# create structured numpy array in python with strings and int

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

i have this:

```
>>> matriz
      [['b8:27:eb:d6:e3:10', '0.428s', '198'],
      ['b8:27:eb:d6:e3:10', '0.428s', '232'],
      ['b8:27:eb:07:65:ad', '0.796s', '180'], 
      ['b8:27:eb:07:65:ad', '0.796s', '255'],
      dtype='<U17']`
```

but i need the column

```
   `matriz[:, [2]] : 
    [['198'],
     ['232'],
     ['180'], 
     ['255']]`
```

to be  int and the other columns to be strings,  i was trying with structured numpy array but i have this error message,

```
 ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'b8:27:eb:d6:e3:10'
 TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

i used

```
  matriz=np.array(matriz, dtype='U17,U17,i4')
```

i'm using numpy version '1.12.1' for raspberry pi 3, i don't know what i'm doing wrong.
thanks a lot

Comment: You really should post your data as text, *not* as images

Comment: Also why do you *want* to do this, if you want mixed datatypes you should be using `pandas`

Comment: Thanks you for the correction, yes, i need to mix those data because i want to know what data from column matriz[:, [2]] are for column matriz[:, [0]]

Comment: do you know if i can do that with pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [484]: x = np.array([['b8:27:eb:d6:e3:10', '0.428s', '198'],
     ...:               ['b8:27:eb:d6:e3:10', '0.428s', '232'],
     ...:               ['b8:27:eb:07:65:ad', '0.796s', '180'], 
     ...:               ['b8:27:eb:07:65:ad', '0.796s', '255']],
     ...:              dtype='<U17')
     ...:
```

You could fetch the last column with an `astype` conversion:

```
In [485]: x[:,2].astype(int)
Out[485]: array([198, 232, 180, 255])
In [486]: x[:,[2]].astype(int)
Out[486]: 
array([[198],
       [232],
       [180],
       [255]])
```

To construct a structured array, you need to provide a list of tuples.  A list of lists or non-structured array with the compound dtype will produce your kind of error.

```
In [487]: np.array([tuple(i) for i in x],'U17,U10,int')
Out[487]: 
array([('b8:27:eb:d6:e3:10', '0.428s', 198),
       ('b8:27:eb:d6:e3:10', '0.428s', 232),
       ('b8:27:eb:07:65:ad', '0.796s', 180),
       ('b8:27:eb:07:65:ad', '0.796s', 255)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<U17'), ('f1', '<U10'), ('f2', '<i8')])
In [488]: _['f2']
Out[488]: array([198, 232, 180, 255])
```

Fields of the structured array are fetched by name.

Answer (score 0):

NumPy works best with homogeneous dtype arrays. Pandas is a good alternative if you have different types.

However, what you ask is possible with NumPy [structured arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html#module-numpy.doc.structured_arrays):

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([['b8:27:eb:d6:e3:10', '0.428s', '198'],
              ['b8:27:eb:d6:e3:10', '0.428s', '232'],
              ['b8:27:eb:07:65:ad', '0.796s', '180'], 
              ['b8:27:eb:07:65:ad', '0.796s', '255']],
             dtype='<U17')

arr = np.core.records.fromarrays(x.transpose(),
                                 formats='<U17,<U17,i4',
                                 names='col1,col2,col3')

print(arr)

rec.array([('b8:27:eb:d6:e3:10', '0.428s', 198),
           ('b8:27:eb:d6:e3:10', '0.428s', 232),
           ('b8:27:eb:07:65:ad', '0.796s', 180),
           ('b8:27:eb:07:65:ad', '0.796s', 255)],
          dtype=[('col1', '<U17'), ('col2', '<U17'), ('col3', '<i4')])
```

Comment: thanks you a lot, i need to mix those data because i want to know what data  from column arr[:, [2]] are for column arr[:, [0]]. Do you know if i can do that from this way?  thanks you...

Comment: `arr['col3']` is how you access a field of the structured array.